# RewriteRule doesn't seem to be working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to rewrite

```
/blog/2016-10-02-my-post
```

to

```
/blog/post.php?s=2016-10-02-my-post
```

Using ModRewrite in .htaccess. I've tried several variations of the following but just keep getting 404's:

```
RewriteRule ^blog/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ /blog/post.php?s=$1 [L]s
```

ModRewrite is working because I've got some very simple test rules working. What am I doing wrong with the above?

Comment: I edited your post because you are rewriting `/blog/2016-10-02-my-post` to `/blog/post.php?s=2016-10-02-my-post` and not the other way around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `[L]s` is giving: `RewriteRule: bad flag delimiters`.

Also, the rule needs to start with `^/`. So this works:

```
RewriteRule ^/blog/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ /blog/post.php?s=$1 [L]
```

Comment: This rule will **never** match as it starts with `^/`. The URL tested in RewriteRule is stripped of leading slashes. The OPs rewrite is correct except for the flag.

Comment: You are right. I missed the `.htaccess` part (I tested in a `VirtualHost`).